# Xcode - how to share photo from iPhone app to Facebook managed page feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

so the problem I'm facing is this:
user takes photo in-app, and shares it on Facebook, but it only gets shared on his own wall. This is rather easy, and I can done that.

However, how to customize the app so the user posts the photo on the wall of some page he manages? Is it even possible? (I mean, it should be in my opinion, but I just don't know how)

Thanks for any and all help!

EDIT:

So far I got here: I can post a photo on Page by my own profile, and I can post a feed update on the page by the page itself. However, I was not able to combine these two things, as in posting the photo on the page by the page. Also created a new question concerning this issue here: 
[ObjC, Facebook Page - posting news feed works, but posting photo does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880426/objc-facebook-page-posting-news-feed-works-but-posting-photo-does-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible because of a bug in the API: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/206254392780441 has the details.

One workaround is to post to the /feed connection of the page and attach an image to the feed story. That image won't be displayed as large as a proper photo upload, but should work OK.

That bug means that posting to the /PAGE_ID/photos connection of a Page using a User access_token will incorrectly upload the photo to the user's /photos connection instead.

Posting to a page's /photos connection will work as expected when using the Page's access_token; the photo will appear on the page's photos page, on the page's timeline, and attributed to the Page itself (i.e 'from' the page)

If your app is specifically for adding content to a page, and has a server-side component, another workaround to get the photos from a user onto the page is to have the users supply a photo to you via your own interface (i.e upload it from the user's device to your server), and use one of the page admins' access_tokens to get a Page access_token and make the upload that way.

Comment: Could you please contribute with more info about the "working" solution (paragraph 5) and possibly a code snippet of how to use Page's access_token?

Comment: You have to go through the facebook API's in depth. I have never implemented it practically. Just a suggestion for you.

Comment: So, I did what you've implied, and the current problem I have is this - I can post a photo to the Page, but it creates post by myself rather then the Page. I have the Page token, however I don't use it in any way, could that be the problem? If so, could you tell me how to use the Token in the way that the photo posts are recognized by the page rather then by myself?
What's weird is that when I send a request for a feed update (status update) to the page in the same way as the Photos (with different params ofc), it creates the post by the page and not by myself...

Comment: So, it turned out your suggestion was the key! Thanks a lot :) You can visit the second question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869314/xcode-how-to-share-photo-from-iphone-app-to-facebook-managed-page-feed ) where I've described the solution more deeply

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the iOS-native sharing options, I would thus checkout the official Facebook SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/